# Does callback of setState happen after( in sync) state is set?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form select with the values of "change" and "cancel".
Everytime I select a different one, I console.log the value of "mySelection"

```
handleSelectChange = e => {
    var myValue = e.target.value
    if (myValue == "change"){
        this.setState({selectText: "Change rent date"})
        this.setState({selection: "sdsd"})
        this.setState({mySelection: "change" }, console.log(this.state.mySelection))
    }
    if (myValue == "cancel"){
        this.setState({selectText: "Cancel a rent"})
        this.setState({selection: "bob"})
        this.setState({mySelection: "cancel"  }, console.log(this.state.mySelection))
    }
}
```

When I select change, it console logs cancel.. when I select cancel, it console logs change. I thought the callback of setState happens after the state is set?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass a function as 2nd parameter of `setState`

```
handleSelectChange = e => {
    var myValue = e.target.value
    if (myValue == "change"){
        this.setState({selectText: "Change rent date"})
        this.setState({selection: "sdsd"})
        this.setState({mySelection: "change" }, () => console.log(this.state.mySelection))
    }
    if (myValue == "cancel"){
        this.setState({selectText: "Cancel a rent"})
        this.setState({selection: "bob"})
        this.setState({mySelection: "cancel"  }, () => console.log(this.state.mySelection))
    }
}
```